# Duda sobre Limpiar un registro capturado con la expresión regular .*

Tags: javascript

gusto en saludarles, quisiera comentar sobre una duda que tengo respecto a limpiar datos basado en la expresión regular .*

Normalmente via herramienta de OCR me ha tocado capturar lo siguiente:

**CAMP 3537 (00) /'**  usando la expresión regular .*

Lo que necesito si me pueden ayudar es mejorar la expresión para poder borrar los caracteres especiales como estos /' y solo me tome letras y números como esto CAMP 3537 (00)

Muchas gracias a todos y espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar esta función, quitando/agregando los caracteres que necesites.

```
function cleanTextString(text)
{
    var specialChars = "!@#$^&%*()+=-[]\/{}|:<>¿?,.";
    for (var i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
       text= text.replace(new RegExp("\\" + specialChars[i], 'gi'), '');
    } 
    text = text.replace(/á/gi,"a");
    text = text.replace(/é/gi,"e");
    text = text.replace(/í/gi,"i");
    text = text.replace(/ó/gi,"o");
    text = text.replace(/ú/gi,"u");
    text = text.replace(/ñ/gi,"n");
    return text;
}
```