# Problema con la validación de campos

Tags: javascript

Tengo 2 validaciones de campo con `javascript` y lo que quiero hacer es que en el `input` de `"txtprimerapellido"` me permita ingresar sólo letras y no números ni caracteres `ascii`.

Cuando hago la validación para números en un campo de DNI si me sale todo correcto y no me deja ingresar letras, pero en el caso del campo "sólo letras" aparece mi problema.

### Esta es mi función creada en javascript:

```
function valida_numero(xinput,tipval){

var xkey = event.keyCode;   
//Validaci�n de enteros
if(tipval=="int")
    if ((xkey < 48) || (xkey > 57)) event.returnValue = false;

//Validaci�n de cadenas

if(tipval=="str")
    if (((xkey != 32) && (xkey < 65))|| ((xkey > 90) && (xkey < 97))) event.returnValue = false;
```

Intenté esto pero no funciona

```
//if ((xkey <46) || (xkey > 57)) event.returnValue = false;

 ----------------input de mi jsp--------------------------

input name="txtPrimerApellido" style="width: 90%"  
onKeyPress="valida_numero(this,'str')" value="<c:out 
value='${bean.strApellidoPaterno}'/>"

onfocus="this.select();nextfield='txtSegundoApellido'"  tabindex="1" <%= 
strEstiloIz %> maxlength="30" >
```

Comment: Y las mayusculas? y los caracteres que estan por fuera de ese rango?? (los acentos, la ñ, otras letras?)... Cual es la necesidad de validar un apellido contra algo?

Comment: Mejor prueba con expresiones regulares

Comment: Es una validación como hace la reniec y como lo muestran en nuestros DNI'S(perú), que te restringe las tildes y minúsculas, en mi campo sólo debe ingresarse letras y no números ni caracteres especiales, ni tildes.

Comment: Hola buenas. Por favor, cambia la etiqueta ya que tienes la etiqueta de java y estas preguntado sobre javascript.

Comment: Puedes ver mi respuesta en [Validar solo letras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/230177/validar-solo-letras-en-javascript/230746#230746). Eso te puede orientar en lo que deseas implementar.

Comment: Quizás esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190066/duda-sobre-limpiar-un-registro-capturado-con-la-expresi%C3%B3n-regular/190074#190074) te oriente. Podrías hacer dos funciones, una para sólo letras o otra sólo para el DNI.

Comment: Puede que este regex te ayude: https://regexr.com/3b0ik

Answer (score 1):

si lo que necesitas es comprobar que el apellido sólo contenga letras puedes validarlo con una expresión regular que solo admita letras (mayúsculas o minúsculas):

```js
function verificarSoloLetras()
  {
   var letras = /^[^\u0000-\u0040\u005B-\u0060\u007B-\u00BF\u02B0-\u036F\u00D7\u00F7\u2000-\u2BFF]+$/;
   if(document.getElementById("cajaDeTexto").value.match(letras))
     {
     console.log("OK");
     }
   else
     {
     console.log("Error");
     }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cajaDeTexto">
<button type="button" onClick="verificarSoloLetras()">Comprobar</button>
```

Regex indicado por kosmosan en los comentarios

Comment: Cambia el regex por este y valdrá para cualquier letra unicode: `([^\u0000-\u0040\u005B-\u0060\u007B-\u00BF\u02B0-\u036F\u00D7\u00F7\u2000-\u2BFF])+`

Comment: parece que va bien salvo para apellidos compuestos (porque no reconoce los espacios), actualizo el ejemplo con el regex que indica @kosmosan

Comment: Es válido para letras/palabras. Aún así, en todo caso, se pueden eliminar los espacios del string de antemano para realizar la comprobación:  `if(docu...).value.replace(/\s/g, '').match(letras))`

Comment: Gracias a todos, estoy viendo estos mensajes después de tiempo, ya me había olvidado, pero gracias, ya lo solucioné todo lo que viene a ser validaciones, y lo hice con expresiones regulares, mi problema era bien sencillo, gracias :)